What embedding (if any) does does Azure Search use, "out the box"
I've been using Azure Search for months now, using an Indexer to load data in from an Azure SQL database. I think use the Azure Open AI functions with the cognitive search extension, to provide essentially a "Bring-You-Own-Data" chatbot experience.
This has been working really well, but I was asked what embedding the process uses, so I tried to find out. I don't know where to look, and am even having doubts now about whether I am using one at all - I assumed loading the data in via the indexer would apply a default embedding to create the vectors and then it all just works, without much effort. So which is it? Is there a default embedding, or am I not using an embedding at all and it's just using full text search or something - although the results have been excellent so I can't imagine it getting much better...

is there a vector field in you index? If yes go to vector profiles there you can find embedding model details. Also have you configured vector search while bringing data to open ai from ai search? if yes there you would have selected the embedding model. Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/vector-search-how-to-configure-vectorizer

There's nothing in vector profiles. But I am using Semantic Search and have a semantic configuration set up. So surely that uses vectorization? I'm confused...

Are you having a vector field in index?

Nope. I didn't set anything up as a vector field.

Then you are not using embedding.

Provide the details on embedding model usage in ai search and azure openai. Please check it. @Sean

When you are having a vector field

go to vector profiles and click on vectorizer you will find the embedding model you are using.

Also, in azure openai "Bring-You-Own-Data" if you check mark the Add vector search to this resource there you need to select the embedding model like below.
Note: You should be having a vector field to use this option.

You were saying as of now it is giving good results, still to improve the results by doing vector search you create an vector field and generate results using Azure OpenAI Embedding skill.
Then integrate with azure openai with Search type as hybrid.

Also, there will be no default embedding used by the search service both in ai search and azure openai you need to add the deployed embedding model to generate vectors for your document and also for search query.
